# Virtual Box bridged adapter find real machine IP

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I want to ask if is there a method to find in my network the real IP of a machine which hosts Virtual Box machines with bridged network adapter. The virtual machines gets real dhcp IP's from the router.

Thank you.

Comment: tracepath will show the ip

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check it from windows machine run this command

```
pathping <IP_from_VM>
```

For linux I don't know the alternative command that works like that.